# Certain Owl Carousel settings not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I have successfully integrated Owl Carousel and some my desired settings are active

However, the navigation and margin and padding sections aren't working...

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    items : 3, 
    nav: true,
    navText: ['<i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-2x"></i>','<i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-2x"></i>'], 
    loop:true,
    stagePadding: 50,
    margin: 10,
    responsiveClass:true,
    dots: false,
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1,
        },
        767:{
            items:2,
        },

    }
});
```

I have checked the console and there are no errors, the js and css is linked and in the case of the arrows, looking at the HTML the font awesome icons aren't even rendered - it's just empty divs for prev and next arrows (which actually work when clicked)

If worse comes to worse I can use CSS to fix the issues manually, but with the margins and paddings its kind of best to have Owl Carousel calculate them

Help appreciated, thanks

Comment: So are you saying that the divs `<i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-2x"></i>` are not even being outputted in your page source?

Comment: Which version of Owl Carousel are you using?

Comment: The latest sir - and yes they are not being outputted

Comment: Please state what version, are you using the beta or not? See my answer below, this may help.. notice the example given in the docs. If you completely remove the `navText` option, does your margin and padding and navigation work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the OWl Carousel docs (http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/docs/api-options.html), you seem to have split the `navText` value out, which might be causing the error.

Try using this instead:

```
navText: [<i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-2x"></i>],
```